# Laravel: one to many relationship returns only one record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a one to many relationship between notification and alerFrequencies table. they have models for both. I wrote this function to extract all the latest `created_at` time stamp from the alerFrequencies table.

Example, if I have one website in my notification table with `created_at` time stamps in the alert table, it should return me the latest time stamp only. If I have 2 websites in the notification table with a different time stamp, it should return the time stamp for the 2 websites apart.

Here it returns only the latest regardless of the number of websites in the notification table. ony one who get a better idea to write the query, i would appreciate all kinds of help and suggestions.

```
public function alert(){
        $alert_timestamp = AlertFrequency::with('notification')->select('created_at')->groupBy('created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
        $alert_timestamp=$alert_timestamp->created_at->toDateTimeString();
        if($alert_timestamp==null){
            return false;
        }       
            return $alert_timestamp;
    }
```

in the database i have to tables notifications and alerFrequencies table, with one to many relationship. the notification_id is a foreign key in the alertFreqency table. notification has columns: is, website url and alertFrequencies has : id. notification_id and created_at. now i want to get the latest created_at for every website in the notification table.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. The above query will only return 1 alert_frequency and **only** the created_at field from the table. These 2 parts do absolutely nothing in your query: `::with('notification')` and `->groupBy('created_at')`. You aren't able to load relationships if you don't include `id` in select (or whatever your foreign key is). And group by won't group anything since you're only selecting the latest (`->first()`) `created_at` field.

Comment: Of course it's returning only one, because in your query you only select the first, at the end of your query ->first() selects the first record, change it to ->get()

Comment: @Levente Nagy with the get it give me error:Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$created_at

Comment: Can you show the database?

Comment: shall i show you the database in chat or ?

Comment: use ->get() instead of ->first(). Then iterate over the received collection using foreach. In the loop you can then access the property created_at.

Comment: @ Cashbee: u r right, i can itrate over the collection. but after all the collection is not the right collection. it should give a collection to a specific website not to all websites as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you are doing wrong. First you are querying `AlertFrequency::with('notification')` while from what I am understanding you might want something like `Notification::with('alertfrequencies')`. The second thing is that you are selecting just one column. Selecting just one column makes the with function useless. Third thing you are doing wrong is grouping by the `created_at` column. This simply does nothing for your needs. You would have to `groupBy('notification_id')`. I wrote the above explanations so you can understand better the logic of your application, while I am giving a possible solution below.

Given that you want the latest timestamp of a notification for each website, then a possible approach would be to add an accessor in you `Notification` model.

```
public function getLastTimestampAttribute(){
    return AlertFrequency::where('notification_id', $this->attributes['id'])->order_by('created_at','desc')->first()->created_at;
}
```

Then you can easily access the latest timestamp for each notification by doing `$notification->last_timestamp`, supposing that `$notification` is your object on the view.

Comment: tnx very much.... It took me about a week and couldn't figure it out. You saved me.... Really appreciate you

Comment: the solution works fine, shall i ask you one question. what should i do if a want to insert created_at method into the lertFrequency table automatically for all websites?

Comment: you mean insert it into a database or insert in database when the record is created? or retrieve the value?

Comment: i mean insert into the database when ever there is a need to insert automatically?

Comment: If you have built your database correctly, then there is no need to insert created_at since it is created automatically